# C# TextChangedイベントを日本語変換前でも発生させる

Tags: c#

お世話になっております。
Visual Studio Community 
C# Windowsフォームアプリケーションにて

TextBoxやRichTextBoxで日本語または全角英数を入力した際に
TextChangedイベントを発生させたいのですが

文字の下に波線が表示されている（変換確定前)の状況では
Enterキーを押して変換確定させない限り
TextChangedイベントが発生しないようです。

変換確定前の文字列入力した際にもTextChangedイベントを呼び出したいのですが
方法、アドバイス、ご意見　いただけませんでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`KeyDown`イベントを使用すればよいのでは。
なお入力中のテキストはこの時点では反映されていませんので、この場合は[`ImmGetCompositionStringW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/windows/desktop/dd318553(v=vs.85).aspx)関数を使用します。

```
[DllImport("imm32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr ImmGetContext(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("Imm32.dll")]
public static extern bool ImmReleaseContext(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hIMC);

[DllImport("Imm32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern int ImmGetCompositionStringW(IntPtr hIMC, int dwIndex, byte[] lpBuf, int dwBufLen);

private const int GCS_COMPSTR = 8;

private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var c = ImmGetContext(textBox1.Handle);

    if (c == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        var buf = new byte[256];

        // IME入力値の取得
        var length = ImmGetCompositionStringW(c, GCS_COMPSTR, buf, buf.Length);
        if (length >= 0)
        {
            var composition = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buf, 0, length);

            // 現在の入力内容
            Console.WriteLine(
                textBox1.Text.Substring(0, textBox1.SelectionStart)
                + composition
                + textBox1.Text.Substring(textBox1.SelectionStart + textBox1.SelectionLength));
        }
        else
        {
            // エラー
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        ImmReleaseContext(textBox1.Handle, c);
    }
}
```

ただ`TextBox`を継承して`WndProc`メソッドで`WM_IME_COMPOSITION`メッセージを処理する方が確実かもしれません。